# Rails: how can I optimize this action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, optimization, methods

The action bellow creates a new comment.

- A user has many statuses
- A status has many comments

How can optimize this action so that `head 401 and return` is not repeated many times.

```
def create
  @user = User.where(id: params[:user_id]).first
  if @user
    if current_user.friend_with?(@user) or current_user == @user
      @status = @user.statuses.where(id: params[:status_id]).first
      if @status
        @comment = @status.comments.build(params[:comment])
        @comment.owner = current_user
        if @comment.valid?
          @comment.save
          current_user.create_activity(:comment_status, @comment, @user)
        else
          head 401 and return
        end
      else
        head 401 and return
      end
    else
      head 401 and return
    end
  else
    head 401 and return
  end
end
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When do you want to return `401`?

1. when a user has not been found
2. when a user is not a current user or is not a friend of that user
3. when a status has not been found
4. when new comment has not been successfully created

Instead of using so many conditionals, you can use methods that raise exceptions. When you do so, you can rescue from that exceptions with the desired behavior (rendering `401`).

So my suggestions for listed conditions are:

1. use `find!` instead of `where` and then `first`.
2. `raise` something, preferably custom exception (`NotAFriendError`)
3. same as 1., use `find!`
4. use `create!`, it's an equivalent to `new` and then `save!` which will raise `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` exception if it fails on validation.

Here's the result:

```
def create
  begin
    @user = User.find!(params[:user_id])
    raise unless current_user.friend_with?(@user) || current_user == @user
    @status = @user.statuses.find!(params[:status_id])
    @comment = @status.comments.
      create!(params[:comment].merge(:owner => current_user))
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    head 401
  end
  # everything went well, no exceptions were raised
  current_user.create_activity(:comment_status, @comment, @user)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a lot of excessive checking and branching in your code, so it can be simplified to this:

```
def create
  success = false

  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  current_user_is_friend = current_user.friend_with?(@user) || current_user == @user

  if @user && current_user_is_friend && @status = @user.statuses.find(params[:status_id])
    @comment = @status.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @comment.owner = current_user
    if @comment.save
      current_user.create_activity(:comment_status, @comment, @user)
      success = true
    end
  end

  render(status: 401, content: '') unless success
end
```

A few things I did:

- Combine a lot of the `if` conditions, since there was no need for them to be separate.
- Change `where(id: ...).first` to `find(...)` since they're the same. Note that, if the `find` fails, it will give a 404. This may make more sense, though (I think it does)
- Don't call `@comment.valid?` right before `@comment.save`, since `save` returns `false` if the object wasn't valid.
- Use `||` instead of `or` for boolean logic ([they're **not** the same](http://devblog.avdi.org/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/)).
- Use `render(status: ..., content: '')` instead of `head ... and return`.
- Use a boolean variable to track the success of the method.

I would advise that you try and pull some of this logic out into models. For example, `User#friend_with` should probably just return true if it's passed the same User.

Comment: `where(:id => ...).first` is not exactly equivalent to `find`, since `find` raises `ActiveRecord:: RecordNotFound` instead of returning nil. That case will now return 404 with a standard error page instead of 401. Additionally, `head 401 and return` will return 401 with no content, whereas `render(status: 401)` will render the template with 401 status.

Comment: can you please explain why are you advising to use `render` without content instead of `head`?

Comment: @shime Because simply `return`ing means that rendering no content is a side-effect, rather than an explicit statement. It's best to state your intent up front instead of relying on side-effects and the reader expecting them.

Answer (score 0):

```
def create
  @user = User.where(id: params[:user_id]).first
  if @user
    if current_user.friend_with?(@user) or current_user == @user
      @status = @user.statuses.where(id: params[:status_id]).first
      if @status
        @comment = @status.comments.build(params[:comment])
        @comment.owner = current_user
        if @comment.valid?
          @comment.save
          current_user.create_activity(:comment_status, @comment, @user)
          everythingOK = true
        end
      end
    end
  end
  head 401 and return unless everythingOK
end
```